# Provisioning did not succeed: Publishing Template

Tags: 2010, publishing-site

I have a rather strange scenario. I upgraded from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 and assumed my permissions will pull through correct, note that I am on AD, which didn't quite work the way I expected.

So, I started re-adding my contributors to their respective sites and found that they are no longer permitted to create new sites or pages. The have Designer, Manage Hierarchy permissions set so I fail to see why, so thought I'd dig around the ULS to find out more:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException:
>   Provisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to initialize some site
>   properties for Web at Url: 'http://blt-webfe-03.ad.za'
>   OriginalException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) > System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))

A quick Google search brings back a lot of information around team sites and other nice things but nothing around publishing templates, so I ran this several times to build a quite a big log and found that after the provisioning of Feature `{22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416}` fails, SharePoint successfully deletes the page, but then complains that my user could not be found in AD?

This is so confusing and I really don't know where else to look. Has anybody else run into this, and come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue - this post http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=181 
solved the issue for me - I had to grant the required users read access to the MasterPage gallery